How can I get the AutoCAD version on Windows in Python?
I am working on a Python script that monitors when AutoCAD is opened in a system. I have tried as follows:
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
process_creation_watcher = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
creation_event = process_creation_watcher()
process_name = creation_event.Caption
print(process_name)

Currently, it prints "acad.exe" for all types of AutoCAD.
AutoCAD has several verticals, like "AutoCAD Civil 3D 2016", "AutoCAD Map 3D 2024", "AutoCAD 2025", "AutoCAD LT 2025", etc.
How can I get the full name of software with version like "AutoCAD Civil 3D 2016" in place of "acad.exe"?
Thanks in advance.
Currently, it prints "acad.exe" for all types of AutoCAD.
AutoCAD has several verticals, like "AutoCAD Civil 3D 2016", "AutoCAD Map 3D 2024", "AutoCAD 2025", "AutoCAD LT 2025", etc.
How can I get the full name of software with version like "AutoCAD Civil 3D 2016" in place of "acad.exe"?
Thanks in advance.
